# How to customize SOAP Fault messages in Mule?

Tags: web-services, soap, exception, esb, mule

How do I send the fault code and fault string in such a way, that after my flow throws an exception, I get the desired error code and message in the SOAP error response (in FaultCode and FaultString fields).

I have a SOAP service that is being called in Mule. I am using a custom-exception-strategy for catching exceptions, and then setting spring-bean properties for **code** and **message** fields. The spring properties are being set, but my SOAP response is still the generic SOAP fault.

Also, I read that only MessagingExceptions can be handled in mule. So, how do I reproduce a messagingExcetion to test my code during development?

Comment: Mule version? Are you using CXF? On what Spring bean are you setting properties? Config maybe?

Comment: I am using Mule 3.2.1 and yes, CXF proxy-service and proxy-client to consume the external web-services.

Comment: I am setting the properties on a custom exception class that extends AbstractException (I am putting this as the class for my custom-exception-strategy too). Is there something wrong?

Comment: I have to use custom-exception-strategy like http://mule.1045714.n5.nabble.com/Return-SOAP-Fault-from-custom-exception-strategy-td2679189.html. The solution I found (http://forums.mulesoft.org/message.jspa?messageID=3068) does not use any exception strategy. Does it mean we cannot use a custom exception strategy and returning customized soap exceptions together?